# Cannot change line width in HTML 5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I build a very simple app to draw rectangles in an image by clicking an `Add` button. However, no matter what properties for `stroke` in `canvas` I changed, the properties remain the same.

In that example, `context.lineWidth` has been set to 1. But the rectangle, drawn after clicking the `Add` button, actually have a much wider line width and also with some transparency (I want the line to be solid and not transparent at all).

May anyone offer some help here?

Here is my code in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqy12b5m/3/).

```js
var img = $('#sourceImage');
var addButton = $('#addButton');
addButton.offset({
    top: img.offset().top + img.height() + 10
});

var boundingBoxId = 'IMG00001_01';

addButton.click(function () {
    console.log(boundingBoxId);
    $('<canvas>').attr({
        id: boundingBoxId
    }).css({
        width: img.width() + 'px',
        height: img.height() + 'px',
        position: 'absolute'
    }).appendTo('#drawArea');

    var canvas = document.getElementById(boundingBoxId);
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.strokeStyle = 'red';
    context.rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.stroke();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drawArea">
    <img id="sourceImage" src="http://www.sixt.com/uploads/pics/bmw_5_sixt-car_rental-B.png" style="position: absolute; border: 1px solid #000000" />
</div>
<button id="addButton">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using CSS to set size of the bitmap. That will only apply to the element itself, not the bitmap. The bitmaps' default size is 300x150 which is what you see gets stretched.

Set the attributes of the element to affect the bitmap, like:

```
$('<canvas>').attr({
    id: boundingBoxId
}).attr({
    width: img.width(),      // important: attributes affect bitmap
    height: img.height()
}).css({
    position: 'absolute'     // affects element
}).appendTo('#drawArea');
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqy12b5m/5/)**

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot! I'm new to HTML 5 and Javascript. Your answer helps me a lot today!

Comment: Hi, I've got one more question. After modifying the code, the line is still a bit transparent (as in your updated fiddle; it seems to only happen when the line width is `1`). May I know why it is transparent? I tried to set the Alpha channel, but didn't find any luck.

Comment: @mintaka it's due to sub-pixeling. Canvas center the pixel on the grid, you can offset it by 0.5 pixels like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cqy12b5m/12/